# 500 URL Rewrite Module Error ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, iis-8

I am running a reverse proxy (RP) server (Win 2012 R2) in my DMZ. That then connects to my LAN server running Win 2008 R2. I also have the same RP server in front of another Win 2012 R2 LAN box.

We're deploying our first ASP.NET Core app on the LAN behind the RP. It works perfect is the LAN box is Win 2012 R2. However, if we move the app to our production Win 2008 R2 machine, it works except when there is a controller that returns a HTML view (instead of XML or JSON). Again, the exact same code works on a Win 2012 R2 LAN box but not a Win 2008 R2 LAN box.

Here's the RP web.config (same for both LAN servers except for the IPs and domain)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.0.0.254/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://10.0.0.254/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://our-public-domain.com/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

On the Win 2008 R2 LAN box, here's the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 5x8x39x8-580x-4xx2-955x-76x4x4685415-->
```

As I said, the configuration on the same RP server when connecting to the Win 2012 R2 or Win 2008 R2 boxes. Additionally, we have other sites on the Window 2008 R2 that do NOT use ASP.NET Core and those work just fine but none have a view as they just return XML, JSON, and text.

Any insight?

Comment: Any change razor pages weren't copied to production server? Any errors you are getting when trying to get a razor page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have Response Rewrite in the rule. This can cause 500 error from URLRewrite module in the RP server if the response is compressed. You can see details by checking the sub statuscode. For Gzip encoding this is normally 500.52 .You can see this in the IIS log of RP server

More details on substatuscode [iis status code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7.0,-iis-7.5,-and-iis-8.0)

if the error is 500.52,check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-part-2-dealing-with-500-52-status-codes/)

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check in control panel that you have installed IIS Express more than one. If you have more than one then 
1.keep the default IIS Express. 
2.Uninstall other.
3.Repair IIS Express